# remove #!/ from url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an annoying directory string in the url bar

```
           mycom.com/#!/
```

I want to remove #!/

I have tried 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !#!/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule #!/$ index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  #!/(.*)$  $1 [L]
```

This assumes (1) that .htaccess doesn't have any problem with #! in a URI, and (2) it's either always at the *beginning* of the URI, or you don't mind discarding whatever comes before it. Note that the resulting URI will be starting without an /, so you may need to add that (or drop / from the pattern).